# Kestrel - Use specific SSL cert already on my machine

Tags: ssl-certificate, kestrel

Optimizely CMS (the artist formerly known as EPiServer) recently released a .Net Core version. I can run my site using Kestrel. But, I want to set a specific url for my site, and I want to use an already existing SSL cert for this url.

The cert is installed on my machine in the WebHosting store.

Here is my Kestrel config:

launchSettings.json

```
"MySampleProject": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "externalUrlConfiguration": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://sampleproject.local.hostname.dev",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
    "Url": "https://sampleproject.local.hostname.dev",
    "Certificate": {
      "Subject": "local.hostname.dev",
      "Store": "WebHosting",
      "Location": "LocalMachine",
      "AllowInvalid": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

In program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, bool isDevelopment)
    {
        
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureCmsDefaults()
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions => serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false);
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                });
        }
```

I assume there is some issue with the config? But I am having a hard time finding documentation around how to do this.

Comment: I don't think there's anything Optimizely/Episerver-specific here?

Comment: No, I dont either. I found a potential solution - I dont love it so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bingo. Found the desired way to do it.

Here is the appsettings

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://sampleproject.local.hostname.dev:8001",
      "Certificate": {
        "Subject": "local.hostname.dev",
        "Store": "webhosting",
        "Location": "LocalMachine"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then in Program.js

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureCmsDefaults()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is "a" solution. I dont think its the best solution, but it works.

Here is my appsettings for Kestrel:

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
    "Url": "https://sampleproject.local.hostname.dev",
    "Certificate": {
      "Subject": "local.hostname.dev",
      "Store": "webhosting",
      "Location": "LocalMachine",
      "AllowInvalid": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Then in my Program.cs

```
var storeName = context.Configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:HttpsInlineCertStore:Certificate:Store"];
            var storeLocationString = context.Configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:HttpsInlineCertStore:Certificate:Location"];
            var storeLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
            if (storeLocationString == "CurrentUser")
            {
                storeLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
            }
            var subject = context.Configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:HttpsInlineCertStore:Certificate:Subject"];
            var port = 8001;

            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions =>
                {
                    // Enable support for HTTP1 and HTTP2 (required if you want to host gRPC endpoints)
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    // Configure Kestrel to use a certificate from a local .PFX file for hosting HTTPS
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(subject, storeName, storeLocation, false), configureOptions: _ => { });
                });
            });
```

The keys thing was how do I point to a cert that wasnt in the default cert store. I manage several sites, and my cert is in that webhosting store. There is an Enum with store names, but webhosting isnt part of that enum. AND, I wanted it in config, not code, so a different developer could have a different set up.

I would like to make it so that it just uses whats in the appsettings and I just call UseKestral() or something and reads from the config. But this at least works.

Comment: I wonder why this simple thing does not work as expected... `builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 7048, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.crt", "localhost.key");
    });
});`